# Sending input from "GET" to xml file in php

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to save my input from html file

```
<form action="skrypt.php" method="GET">
Author: <input type="text" size="20" name="author" /><br>
Message: <input type="text" size="80" name="message" />
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

to xml file by using php. My code looks like this:

```
$author = $_GET["author"];
$message = $_GET["message"];
$file = 'file.xml';

if (!empty($author) && !empty($message)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $sxe = simplexml_import_dom($xml);
    $entry = $sxe->addChild("entry");
    $sxe ->addChild("author", $author);
    $sxe ->addChild("message", $message);
    
    $xml->asXml($file);
}
header('location: index.html');
?>
```

I would like to allow multiple entries. With each input, the new entry would be made and added to the existed file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry>
    <author>bill</author>
    <message>im sending a message</message>
</entry>
<entry>
    <author>tom</author>
    <message>hello</message>
</entry>
```

Is it possible to make my output look like the one above? Because I'm getting this one instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry>
    <author>bill</author>
    <message>im sending a message</message>
<entry/><author>tom</author><message>hello</message></entry>
```

After trying to add author and message to $entry rather than to $sxe, I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry>
    <author>bill</author>
    <message>im sending a message</message>
<entry>
    <author>tom</author>
    <message>hello</message>
</entry>
</entry>
```

so I don't think it is the answer.
Can someone explain this to me? I would be grateful.

Comment: the problem is that i want to get <entry> text </entry> and then after another input <entry> text </entry> and im getting only <entry> text <entry/> text </entry>

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding the `author` and `message` to `$entry` rather than to `$sxe`? It seems you're missing the `<entry>` tags because you're adding the child entries to the main one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML you're trying to create is not valid. An XML document must have only one root node, but you have two (`<entry>...</entry> <entry>...</entry>`).

You should instead try to generate something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entries>
  <entry>
    <author>bill</author>
    <message>im sending a message</message>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <author>tom</author>
    <message>hello</message>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

I've not used PHP for XML manipulation before, but I think you'll need something like this:

```php
if (!empty($author) && !empty($message)) {
    try {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
      $sxe = simplexml_import_dom($xml);
    } catch (exception $e) {
      $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><entries></entries>');
    }

    // Add new <entry>
    $newEntry = $sxe->addChild("entry");
    $newEntry->addChild("author", $author);
    $newEntry->addChild("message", $message);
    
    $sxe->asXml($file);
}
```

As comments have mentioned, this fixes a couple of other things:

- `$xml->asXml($file);` should be `$sxe->asXml($file);`
- `$sxe ->addChild("author",..` should be `$newEntry->addChild("author",..`

Comment: I'm getting a Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): Cannot add child. Parent is not a permanent member of the XML tree

Comment: its about this line `$newEntry = $sxe->entries->addChild("entry");`

Comment: @martae I've updated the code snippet with a better version. This should fix the issue you're seeing, and also allow the code to work even if the file doesn't exist.